# At the time of the giving of the parshah of Nirtza (of avadim), was the avoda done by the Bchoros?

Tags: slave-serve-eved-avadim, temple-service-avoda

Or was it done by the kohanim at that time?

[The din of nirtza is briefly to make a hole in the ear of a slave who wants to continue serving his master, he becomes a slave until Yovel.]

The question is if we would apply the din of an eved who is a kohein, that can't become a nirtza since he must be shav lmishpachto and not a baal mum, to the bchoros as well.

Comment: Did eved ivri apply in the dessert before yovel did?